# Ошибка: Getters of lazy classes cannot be fina

Tags: kotlin, rest, spring-boot, jpa

Создаю REST Spring Boot сервер на Kotlin. Использовал database - first подход и автоматически сгенерировал сущности при помощи встроенного в Intellij инструмента.
При старте сервера выскакивают ошибки:

```
2020-01-12 15:09:14.387 ERROR 23016 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer      : HHH000112: Getters of lazy classes cannot be final: ru.madbrains.smartfridgemanager.server.model.MealplanEntity.name
2020-01-12 15:09:14.391 ERROR 23016 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer      : HHH000243: Setters of lazy classes cannot be final: ru.madbrains.smartfridgemanager.server.model.MealplanEntity.name
2020-01-12 15:09:14.391 ERROR 23016 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer      : HHH000112: Getters of lazy classes cannot be final: ru.madbrains.smartfridgemanager.server.model.MealplanEntity.refRecipeEntities
2020-01-12 15:09:14.391 ERROR 23016 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer      : HHH000243: Setters of lazy classes cannot be final: ru.madbrains.smartfridgemanager.server.model.MealplanEntity.refRecipeEntities
```

Сама сущность выглядит вот так:

```
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "mealplan", schema = "public", catalog = "smartfridgemanagerdatabase")
open class MealplanEntity {
    @get:Id
    @get:Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    var id: Int? = null
    @get:Basic
    @get:Column(name = "name", nullable = true)
    var name: Int? = null

    @get:OneToMany(mappedBy = "refMealplanEntity")
    var refRecipeEntities: List<RecipeEntity>? = null

    override fun toString(): String =
            "Entity of type: ${javaClass.name} ( " +
                    "id = $id " +
                    "name = $name " +
                    ")"

    // constant value returned to avoid entity inequality to itself before and after it's update/merge
    override fun hashCode(): Int = 42

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false
        other as MealplanEntity

        if (id != other.id) return false
        if (name != other.name) return false

        return true
    }
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте к переменным open, примерно как тут:

```
var id: Long = 0L
open var accountNonExpired: Boolean = true
open var accountNonLocked: Boolean = true
open var credentialsNonExpired: Boolean = true
open var enabled: Boolean = true

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])

open var roles: Set<Role> = HashSet()
```

Comment: Я еще убрал префиксы "@get:" перед аннотациями. Не знаю почему, но с ними,видимо, какие то проблемы